# How to construct the matrix in the equation $Ax=b$ in the HHL algorithm?

Tags: hhl-algorithm

I am trying to apply the HHL algorithm to a fluid mechanics problem, but I can't figure how to construct the matrix for the equation $ Ax=b $. Specifically, I am trying to reproduce this [paper](https://www.sto.nato.int/publications/STO%20Educational%20Notes/STO-EN-AVT-377/EN-AVT-377-01.pdf) in code (page 43).  Could someone explain how they got to that form of the matrix? It has to do with the central difference scheme, but I don't get where the 2's come from.

Answer (score 2):

That bit of the paper looks quite misleading. If you look at Figure 31, the matrix is clearly not tridiagonal, but can have up to 4 off-diagonal elements (corresponding to the 4 neighbours of each site, and hence terms in Eq. 76). I *guess*, without having worked through the details, that the 2s appear as a result of the boundary conditions: if, as claimed, the matrix is Laplacian, then the diagonal element (always -4) is equal to - sum of all elements on that row. But at the boundaries, you only connect to 2 or 3 other vertices, so it makes sense.